# rails3 how to redirect_to new page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first post.

First of all, I apologize my poor English. Actually, I'm not confident whether I can tell what I think, cause English is not my first language.

Anyway, I'm making online test program with Rails 3, based on Railscasts 196-197 nested form.

Though that episodes are out of dates, I could make it helped with stackoverflow and google.

The problem is taking examination form for students and auto grading system.

DB table is constructed like this.

```
survey | question 1 | answer 1 | answer 2
-- answer 3
-- ...
-- question 2 -- answer 1
-- ...
-- ...
```

The idea is simple. `In answer model, there are two boolean columns, correct and user_answer. Teacher can check correct answer while making examination, and students can check user_answer while taking examination.`

In the view survey/show.html.erb I made another form for taking examination. After students fill the check box and pressed submit button, auto grading will be done, in grading method in survey controller. and finally they can see the result of test.

This is survey/show.html.erb It's working well.(I can see check box and label as I want)

```
<h1><%= @survey.name %></h1>
 <%= form_tag({:controller => "surveys", :action => "grading"}) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
   <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
   <li>
   <%= question.content %>
     <ol class="answers">
     <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box(answer.user_answer, answer)  %>
        <%= label("answer_".concat(answer.id.to_s).to_sym, answer.content) %>
      </li>
     <% end %>
     </ol>
   </li>
   <% end %>
  </ol>

  <div><%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "submit") %></div>
<% end %>
```

but I'm not sure whether answer.user_answer can be saved correctly. because I can't make and see result pages.

I'm trying to use redirect_to method. For this, I wrote grading method in survey_controller

```
 def grading
    #@survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @survey = Survey.new

    redirect_to results_url
  end
```

and made survey/results.html.erb file(which contains result of test). but not working.

I put this line on config/routes.rb but still not working.

```
  match "surveys/grading" => "surveys#grading", :via => :post
```

Please let me know any idea related to this.

Thanks, advanced.

Answer (score 0):

for redirecting to results path

make a method as `result` in `surveys cotroller`

```
def results
end
```

**in routes.rb**

```
resources :surveys do
 collection do
   get 'results'
 end
end

run rake routes
```

see the url generated for results, it may be results_surveys

```
def grading
    #@survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @survey = Survey.new

    ##changed as per the rake routes
    redirect_to results_surveys_path
end
```

Hope this could help

Comment: I think it would be survey_results_path(@survey).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! Debadatt! You save my life!! I hope to vote your answer, but I can't because I need some reputation. sorry. Swards, I'm sorry but Debadatt's answer is right for me. Anyway thank you guys for helping me!

Comment: @user2681054 : you can accept this answer also.. if you found valuable :)