# Rails 3 : How can I make auto grading system nested_form based online test system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

[I'm still making online test program.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223716/rails3-how-to-redirect-to-new-page)

This is my model.

Survey

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:content].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
```

Question : there is is_correct column which indicates whether students get the right answer or not.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Answer : there is correct column which teacher checks making the survey(test), and there is user_answer column which students mark taking the test.

```
class Answer < ActviveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
```

and I made taking exam interface on show.html.erb in survey views. So if students fill this check box and click the submit button, they can get their result page. but I can't show the result in the result page.

This is my survey controller.

```
  def grading
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.user_id = current_user.id

    if @survey.questions.answers.user_answer and @survey.questions.answers.correct
         @survey.questions.is_correct = true
    end

    redirect_to results_surveys_path(@survey)
  end

  def results
  end
```

The error message I saw is 'undefined method `answers' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation'. I thought that there were problem between question and answer table...

I thought auto grading part is easy, but I was wrong. I have no idea about this and I don't have any reference, except your help.

any idea welcome.

Thanks advanced.

**Updated Question**

Here is another question.

Now I can access to nested objects.(I think and I hope) but the result page(result.html.erb in survey views) can't show any result : "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".

result.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @survey.name %></h1>
<h3><%= @survey.user.username %></h3>
```

As I told in [previous link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223716/rails3-how-to-redirect-to-new-page), I have another form_tag in show.html.erb in survey views. then redirect to the result page with routes.rb.

```
  resources :surveys do
   collection do
     get 'results'
   end
  end
```

I thought I can show the result page using is_correct column in question tables.

I didn't write anything in the result method in survey controller. Because when I redirect the page I wrote like this. Which means using @survey in result method, doesn't it?

```
    redirect_to results_surveys_path(@survey)
```

Here is the result of rake routes.

```
seriousin@classcasts:~/ClassCasts$ rake routes | grep survey
         results_surveys GET    /surveys/results(.:format)                  surveys#results
                 surveys GET    /surveys(.:format)                          surveys#index
                         POST   /surveys(.:format)                          surveys#create
              new_survey GET    /surveys/new(.:format)                      surveys#new
             edit_survey GET    /surveys/:id/edit(.:format)                 surveys#edit
                  survey GET    /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#show
                         PUT    /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#update
                         DELETE /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#destroy
         surveys_grading POST   /surveys/grading(.:format)                  surveys#grading
seriousin@classcasts:~/ClassCasts$
```

I think my basic idea caused all of my problem. Here is my survey controller.

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def grading
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.user_id = current_user.id

    @survey.questions.each do |question|
     question.auto_check     
  end

    redirect_to results_survey_path(@survey)
  end

  def results
      @survey = Survey.where(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  def edit
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])
    @survey.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  def update
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @survey.destroy
  end

end
```

as you can see, I'm using show page in survey views as another input form with grading method. I can use '@survey = Survey.new' in create method, it makes sense! but as I wrote in grading method, it generates another new survey, I think.
So I need to change that line. can you please help me?

**Sending data**

OK. when I submit in _form.html.erb in survey views, I can send data like this.

```
  Parameters: {"id"=>"14", "survey"=>{"name"=>"The First Test!", "description"=>"This is the first test!", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"41", "content"=>"Question 2", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"66", "content"=>"Answer 2 of Question 2", "correct"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"67", "content"=>"Answer 1 of Question 2", "correct"=>"1"}}}, "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"42", "content"=>"Question 1", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"68", "content"=>"Answer 2 of Question 1", "correct"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"69", "content"=>"Answer 1 of Question 1", "correct"=>"1"}}}, "1376575795482"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "content"=>"Question 3", "answers_attributes"=>{"1376575802879"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "content"=>"Answer 1 of Question 3", "correct"=>"0"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Update Survey", "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/vNuB5Ck3QM5p+5ksL3tlmb+ti5nTA/qS96+vbPQkNw="}
```

This is OK. but because of form_tag in show.html.erb, show page contains another input form.

```
 <%= form_tag({:controller => "surveys", :action => "grading"}) do %>
```

after submit again in show.html.erb I want to redirect to the results.html.erb with proper result. but there are errors like this.

```
Started POST "/surveys/grading" for 110.174.136.30 at Thu Aug 15 23:19:52 +0900 2013
Processing by SurveysController#grading as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "#<Answer:0x7fafd8c5f5a0>"=>"1", "#<Answer:0x7fafd95704a0>"=>"0", "#<Answer:0x7fafd9116a58>"=>"1", "authenticity_token"=>"/vNuB5Ck3QM5p+5ksL3tlmb+ti5nTA/qS96+vbPQkNw=", "#<Answer:0x7fafd8d03a38>"=>"0", "commit"=>"Submit", "#<Answer:0x7fafd8cfc580>"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"results", :id=>#<Survey id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, attempts: nil, user_id: 12, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, :controller=>"surveys"}):
  app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:31:in `grading'
```

Do you think that I need to change whloe answering mechanism?

Comment: `@survey.questions` is an ActiveRecord::Relation containing all the questions - you can't call `answers` on it. `answers` is for a single question.

Comment: so I changed @survey.questions.answers.user_answer to @survey.question.answer.user_answer but still I have a problem. 'undefined method `question'.

Comment: Yes, because a `@survey` has multiple questions, not just one. I recommend getting a Rails tutorial and following it, because you're missing a lot of knowledge on basic concepts. I like http://manning.com/bigg2/.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! Now I have a new book list that I must buy. I'm gonna buy read it soon. Actually I have "Head First Rails" but useless, because it is out of dated.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, you are trying to call your method on an array. your have to iterate over it and then you can assign any value to it. you can do some re-factoring in your code as well to avoid loops.

in your grading method, do this:

```
def grading
  @survey = Survey.new
  @survey.user_id = current_user.id

  @survey.questions.each do |question|
    question.auto_check     
  end

  redirect_to results_surveys_path(@survey)
end
```

In your Question model write a method auto_check like this:

```
 def auto_check
   answers.each do |answer|
    is_correct = true  if answer.user_answer and answer.correct                      
    self.save!
   end
 end
```

I think it is a better approach.Thanks.

Updated Answer:

Whenever you try to pass an id in your path, that means that is a member function, if you are defining collection in your routes, that means you cannot pass an id in that(As you routes output shows. Have a keen look into it). change your routes like this:

```
resources :surveys do
  member do
   get 'results'
  end
end
```

Now you can access your url like this:

```
  results_survey_path(@survey)
```

and in your `results` method :

```
 def results
  @survey = Survey.where(params[:id])
 end
```

Hope, now it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. Now I can understand a little bit of how I can access to nested object. But I still have problem on the result pages. So I updated my Question. I hope all you guys help me.

Comment: you can view your available routes like this: rake routes | grep survey
this way you can see all your available routes for your survey resource. and paste the result here.

Comment: Oh, I updated my Question including the result of rake routes. Thanks advanced.

Comment: Thanks again, Rails Guy! Unfortunately another Routing error has been occurred : 'No route matches {:action=>"results", :id=>#<Survey id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, attempts: nil, user_id: 12, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, :controller=>"surveys"}' It might be caused by using survey controller repeatedly. I updated my question.

Comment: because you have to save your survey first, after that you can send it here. what are the fields in your survey table.

Comment: You're right. I checked in rails console. There are no data in Answer table. I updated my question about cause of the problem that I think. please check.

Comment: There is so much code over here. please keep your code in some repository like github. I will make changes into it.

Comment: Till then have a look at this : http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I am not able to understand the answering system in your application, please push some test data, So I can test with those data.